# solving for the DE for $y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let 
\begin{equation}
y=\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{1}{x}
\end{equation}
How do i solve it? I tried to do it by separable variables but having 3 variables confuses me. Maybe when integration i can evaluate in the interval $[0,t]$?

Comment: Do you know what the context of this question is? Is this something you encountered in a basic undergrad differential equations class, or somewhere else?

Comment: The question is probably incomplete.

Comment: The equation, as written, already expresses $y$ in terms of $x$ and $x'(t)$.

Comment: @Decaf-Math yes i've been given that $y$ are the days passed during an experiment. $x$ is cell concentration and $t$ is the time.

Comment: What is the difference between $y$ and $t$? Is $y$ a step function taking only integer values, as it counts days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y$ is a constant,
$$yt+c=\log x.$$

If $y$ is a function of $t$,

$$\int y(t)\,dt=\log x.$$

If $y$ is a function of $x$,

$$t=\int\frac{dx}{x\,y(x)}.$$

If $y$ is a known function of both, you are stuck.

---

But if you need to solve for $y$, all this is useless.